# Wordpress Featured image

Tags: image, wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-featured-image

I am using Media Grid pulugin and have used this code to populate a form field on the next page using Contact Form 7 shortcode

```
<li id = "info">
<?php 
global $post;
echo '<a href="http://69.195.124.104/~martiob8/request-info?work='.urlencode(get_the_title($post_id)) .'">Request Info</a>'; ?> 

        </li>
```

So what I want to do now is when the "request info" link is clicked display the image for that post next to the form. I'm not exactly sure how to get the $mg_id to pass to the next page or how to catch it on the next page. I'm not really sure how to ask this question. 
I know I'm probably making this harder than it is. I have tried using query_args but it pulls all the images I want to display the single image from that particular post that is echoed in the href.
I hope someone understands this it's like when you click on an image at a store and it opens the page with the image on it. 
I can find how to get multiple images but not just the single image that is in the lightbox from media grid.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `$mg_id` in your code?

Comment: You don't need to declare `global $post` unless you are inside of a function, and it doesn't look like you are.

Comment: Also, you may want to ask this on wordpress.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thank you I will ask it there. I found the global $post in another post and that is how they said to do it to get it to fill the contact form field. It works but I also want to bring the image with it. The $mg_id is declared in a function at the top of the page. When the user clicks the image in the media grid it opens a lightbox and the mg_id shows in the address bar. I can see it but can't figure out how to get it to the other page next to the contact form. I can pull all the images with query args but I only want the image related to that particular post. Thanks